# How can two generic linked list in swift can be compared?

Tags: swift, generics, iequatable

I have a generic linked list and I can check if two linked list are equal if each of the node value are same and are in order.
I have a function which divides linked list in two part and later I want to check two list has same value in it's node.

```
func divideList(atIndex index:Int) -> (first: LLGeneric<T>?,second: LLGeneric<T>?)
```

I looking it for my use case where I can check palindrome in linked list after dividing and then comparing ( after reversing one list).

**Note:** my linked list node is generic something like

```
   class LLGenericNode<T> {
    var value: T
    var next: LLGenericNode?
    weak var previous: LLGenericNode?
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Comment: You want a function to check if a list is "palindrome"?

Comment: @LucaAngeletti, No. Sorry for confusion. What I am looking exatly is some sort of equatable method to compare these generic nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compare values you have to require that `T` is `Equatable`:

```
class LLGenericNode<T: Equatable> {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can implement `==` by comparing the values first.
If the values are equal, the list tails are compared recursively.

```
extension LLGenericNode: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: LLGenericNode<T>, rhs: LLGenericNode<T>) -> Bool {
        if lhs.value != rhs.value {
            return false
        }
        switch (lhs.next, rhs.next) {
        case (nil, nil):
            // Both tails are == nil:
            return true
        case let (lvalue?, rvalue?):
            // Both tails are != nil:
            return lvalue == rvalue // Recursive call
        default:
            // One tails is nil and the other isn't:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is awesome especially the switch statment inside "return lvalue == rvalue // Recursive call"

Comment: This could lead to an infinite loop if the linked list has a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner solution: It should be enough to define a generic `T: Equatable`, making sure on overloading the `==` operator, you compare the current values and the next nodes.

Note that with `lhs.next == rhs.next` you'll cover both recursion and nullability in one shot:

```
class Node <T: Equatable>: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Bool {
        lhs.value == rhs.value && lhs.next == rhs.next
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very elegant. It uses that there is a `==` operator taking two *optional* operands and “doing the right thing”.

Comment: Didn't work for me since == overrides default implementation, thus running indefinitely